# How mock IConfigurationReader

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have interface and class ConfigurationReader:

```
public interface IConfigurationReader
{
  string GetAppSetting(string settingName);
}

public class ConfigurationReader : IConfigurationReader
{
  public string GetAppSetting(string settingName)
  {
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName];
  }
}
```

I'm trying mock IConfigurationReader, but I don't know how do it

```
[Fact]
public void ConfigurationReaderGetConfigSettingTest()
{
  // arrange
  string appKeyName = "pathTemp";
  const string currentTempPath = @"C:\Temp\";

  // act
  var mock = new Mock<IConfigurationReader>();
  mock.Setup(x => x.GetAppSetting(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(currentTempPath);
}
```

Comment: Mock seems to be correctly set up. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Now you need to test your component using the mock.